# How can I keep track of visibility of my text view in each page in a viewpager2?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, visibility

So this is my code. I am trying to create what looks like a PPT slideshow of images with their title and description in my application.

I have the below code and I am stuck on how to allow the user to:

- When he gets into the slideshow he would get the images, with a title and text "description" for each.
- when "ENTER" is pressed set the text on that image to invisible.
- When the user navigates to the right, the next view(s) would contain a text and Image.
  -When the user navigates back left the text view that he set invisible should still be invisible and the has the option to get it to become visible again by just pressing enter.

The last part is what I am stuck on, as I am not able to figure out how each "Linear Layout" inside my viewpager would remember its visibility and act accordingly. (i.e. gets back to visible once it was invisible and vice versa).

I appreciate your input.

Please find the code below:

My ViewPager XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_main_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/default_background"
    tools:context=".PowerPointActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

My views XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_item_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_item_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_item_main_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_parent">

        <!--            the linear layout below was not initially here but I was trying to have a layout for each child.-->
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_item_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_child"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_child"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:text="Topic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_pager_item_about"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:elegantTextHeight="true"
            android:text="@string/about_topic"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fragment_pager_item_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_pager_item_title"
            app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="left" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Adapter Class:

```
public class PowerpointAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    private List<Image> mPowerPointList;

    static class PagesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mViewImageView;
        private TextView mTitleView;
        private TextView mDescriptionView;
        private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

        public PagesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Timber.i("PagesViewHolder");
            mViewImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_imageView);
            mTitleView = itemView.findViewById((R.id.fragment_pager_item_title));
            mDescriptionView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_about);
            mLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_child);
        }
    }

    public PowerpointAdapter(List<Image> mPowerPointList) { this.mPowerPointList = mPowerPointList;}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Timber.i("onCreateViewHolder");
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_item, parent, false);
        return new PagesViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Timber.i("onBindViewHolder");
        PagesViewHolder mViewHolder = (PagesViewHolder) holder;
        Image powerpoint = mPowerPointList.get(position);
        mViewHolder.mViewImageView.setImageResource(powerpoint.getTrialImage());
        mViewHolder.mTitleView.setText(powerpoint.getTitle());
        mViewHolder.mDescriptionView.setText(powerpoint.getDescription());
        mViewHolder.mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()  {
        Timber.i("getItemCount");
        return mPowerPointList.size();}
```

My activity class:

```
// for a one image display, the image can be treated similarly to a powerpoint.

public class PowerPointActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Timber.i("onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager_main);
        ConstraintLayout mLayout = findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_main_parent);
        mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Transparent_black);
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_viewPager2);
        setUpPagerAdapter();
    }
    /**
     * this method will set up the adapter
     */
    private void setUpPagerAdapter() {
        Timber.i("SetUpPagerAdapter");
        PowerpointAdapter pagerAdapter = new PowerpointAdapter(fetchDummyData());
        viewPager2.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
    }
    /**
     * @return this method will return dummy data in form of list
     */
    private List<Image> fetchDummyData() {
        Timber.i("fetchDummyData in Power Point Activity");
        List<Image> powerpointList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] dummyArrDescriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_str_descriptions_for_powerPoints);
        String[] dummyArrTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_str_titles_for_powerPoints);
        for (int index = 0; index < dummyArrTitles.length; ++index) {
            Image image = new Image(dummyArrTitles[index], dummyArrDescriptions[index], R.drawable.ppt_image);
            powerpointList.add(image);
        }
        return powerpointList;
    }
    /**
     * this method handles slideshow navigation
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Timber.i("OnKeyDown");
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT: {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(viewPager2.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                Toast.makeText(PowerPointActivity.this, "Left pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT: {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(viewPager2.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                Toast.makeText(PowerPointActivity.this, "Right pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: {
                Toast.makeText(PowerPointActivity.this, "Back pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                super.onBackPressed();
                break;
            }

            // todo: Fix the visibility of each page description

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER: {
                if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_child).isShown()) {
                    Timber.i("It is shown. Setting it to not shown! "+ viewPager2.getCurrentItem() + " now.");

               // here this specific child's text should be set to invisible and remembered.     findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_child).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    LinearLayout mLayout = findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_child);
                    Animation outFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out);
                    mLayout.startAnimation(outFade);
                    mLayout.startAnimation(outFade);
                    break;
                } else {
                    Timber.i("It is now not shown. Setting it to shown! " + viewPager2.getCurrentItem() + " now.");
                    LinearLayout mLayout = findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_child);
                    Animation aniFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
                    mLayout.startAnimation(aniFade);
                    mLayout.startAnimation(aniFade);
                    findViewById(R.id.fragment_pager_item_child).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter) we can find that the `Adapter` holds the following responsibilities:

> - Acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view.
> - Provides access to the data items
> - Responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

So basically it's not the View's job to remember the child's visibility and act upon it. It's `PowerpointAdapter` responsibility.

You need a status field in your `Image` object and change it when the view visibility is changed. Also, don't forget to set the view visibility according to this status variable.

For example:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Timber.i("onBindViewHolder");
        PagesViewHolder mViewHolder = (PagesViewHolder) holder;
        Image powerpoint = mPowerPointList.get(position);
        mViewHolder.mViewImageView.setImageResource(powerpoint.getTrialImage());
        mViewHolder.mTitleView.setText(powerpoint.getTitle());
        mViewHolder.mDescriptionView.setText(powerpoint.getDescription());
        if(powerpoint.isLayoutVisibile){ 
          mViewHolder.mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
          mViewHolder.mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

And Inside your `ClickListener` you should change this field and notify the `PowerpointAdapter` of these changes.